# Delphi: Send email through Outlook with multiple attachments

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010, delphi-xe

Hello all experts,

```
procedure TForm1.domail(Sender: TObject; fromname, fromadd, sub, toadd, thedocdone, theacc: string; body: widestring);
const
  olMailItem = 0;
var
  Outlook: OLEVariant;
  vmailitem: variant;
  Attachment: TIdAttachment;
  savetofol: string;
begin
  try
    Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  except
    Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  end;
  vmailitem := Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem);
  vmailitem.Recipients.Add(toadd);
  vmailitem.ReplyRecipients.Add('email@email.com');
  vmailitem.Subject := sub;
  vmailitem.body := 'SENT: ' + formatdatetime('dd mmmm yyyy - hh:nn am/pm', now) + #13#10 + body;
  vmailitem.ReadReceiptRequested := true;
  vmailitem.importance := 2;
  if thedocdone <> 'NIL' then
  begin
    vmailitem.Attachments.Add(thedocdone, 1, 1, 'SBSA_' + theacc);
    if ansipos('string1', lowercase(toadd)) <> 0 then
    begin
      vmailitem.Attachments.Add('*manual path', 1, 2, '*manual name');
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Adding consent letter to mail...');
    end;
    if ansipos('string2', lowercase(toadd)) <> 0 then
    begin
      vmailitem.Attachments.Add('*manual path', 1, 2, '*manual name');
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Adding consent letter to mail...');
    end;
    savetofol := extractfilepath(thedocdone) + copy(extractfilename(thedocdone), 0, length(extractfilename(thedocdone)) - 8);
    vmailitem.saveas(savetofol + '_eml.doc', 4); // ^ +'.doc'
  end;
  // vmailitem.clear;
  vmailitem.Send;
  Outlook := Unassigned;
end;
```

With the above piece of code i am able to attach to outlook and send out an email and attach an attachment to that mail...

My problem is that IT WONT attach the 2nd attachment... ??? i have tried every which way using different methods to do this but i just cannot get the 2nd attachment to attach to the mail...

Please help...

Comment: why use outlook? won't it be easier just to create e-mail and send it from your program ?

Comment: what dos it mean "it won't attach" ? what error exception it gives to you ?
did you made sure u use different attachment names? did you make sure you use file formats / filename extensions that Outlook does not consider dangerous? is it correct both #2 and #3 attachments have the same `1, 2` indices ?

Comment: 1 I need to use outlook so that that account inside outlook has a record    
2 No error just doesn't attach the 2nd attachment
3 yes they are different file names 
4 yes they are pdf's being attached
5 #2 #3 are different pdf's if string1 then attach #2 if string2 then attach #3, #2#3 will never be attach at the same time

Comment: okay well you have got to be kidding me...
 as i finished typing out the comment i was attemping another idea against my program with information that i got from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864730.aspx which says .save after each attachment... and its working now so thanks anyways....

Comment: Glad it worked. Well, I just observed you loose the value returned by Attachments.Add . I just two days ago faced similar task, so I ended generating and sending mail from the program. Logging is made by a special read-only mailbox, and my program BCC every letter to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Attachments Object (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864730.aspx):

> To ensure consistent results, always save an item before adding or
>   removing objects in the Attachments collection of the item.

Wrong:

```
vmailitem.Attachments.Add();
vmailitem.Attachments.Add();
vmailitem.Attachments.Add();
```

Right:

```
vmailitem.Attachments.Add();
vmailitem.save;
vmailitem.Attachments.Add();
vmailitem.save;
vmailitem.Attachments.Add();
vmailitem.save;
```

Comment: Could you add some further information around your answer? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer